# Identity provider and bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks

I know that for security reasons we cannot save a different address in the bookmarks that the one we are visiting, but it is quite annoying in my case.

We have the secured site and the idp site in the same domain. When the customer arrives to the secured site (https://mysite.domain.com), he is redirected to the login page (https://idp.domain.com), with url parameters received from the secured website.

The fact is that if the customer tries to save a bookmark when in the login page, it should save the secured site url (https://mysite.domain.com), not the idp (https://idp.domain.com) who needs extra information for the authentication process flow.

I'm surprised I didn't see anything about it yet.

Anyone has a solution ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of how your IP and website are hosted, how they redirect the user (to which urls), which parameters are added to these urls, how these parameters are verified and how/when the user tries to save a bookmark.

Comment: @Progman fine by you now ?

Comment: Why should the bookmark created on the `idp.domain.com` "should save" actually the URL `mysite.domain.com`? The bookmark for the host/URL `idp.domain.com` is obviously for that host/URL, not for a different one.

Comment: Can you detect this situation with the outdated authentication information and redirect the user back to the `mysite.domain.com` URL?

Comment: the idp is not used only by mysite.domain.com. If you know identity server logic, you know that the secured site(s) will redirect to idp for authentication, giving specific information so the idp site knows where it should redirect with authentication information.

Comment: You can't prevent the user from making any bookmarks for any site. But when the user is open the `idp.domain.coom` bookmark with obsolete authentication information and you can detect that, you can redirect the user back to `mysite.domain.com` (without authentication information) and that site will detect that the authentication information are missing. From there the normal authentication process begins. Please [edit] your question to include a description why a bookmark for `idp.domain.com` is problematic and why you can't detect and solve that situation (like redirect the user back).

Comment: this is not a bad idea @Progman. Didn't think about it. You should submit as a response.

Comment: arfff. In fact, IDP react as it has an valid token, and redirects to mysite.domain.com, but this one never finishes opening @Progman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was if a customer bookmarked IDP.

1. The user clicks on the bookmark
2. The login page of the IDP is presented
3. after authentication, user is redirected to website
4. website has no storage data of OIDC, so exception

Changed the website so

5. redirect to website root. If no token, storage of OIDC data and redirect to IDP.
6. IDP has data from previous login and resends auth token and redirect to website.
7. now localstorage data matches data received from IDP.